# cxf-xjc-plugin: generate javax instead of jakarta imports

Tags: java, maven, cxf-xjc-plugin

How to configure latest `org.apache.cxf` plugin to generate java classes with **javax** instead of jakarta imports?

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extensions>
                        <extension>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-dv:4.0.0</extension>
                    </extensions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/gen/java</sourceRoot>
                            <xsdOptions>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xslt/MySchema.xsd</xsd>
                                    <packagename>some.package</packagename>
                                </xsdOption>
                            </xsdOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Downgrading plugin to version `2.7.0` helps but it has problems with generating javaDocs, e.g. `>` signs are not escaped properly.

Comment: I think javax or jakarta are bound to the plugin version if it doesn’t specify a configuration option to change this.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe some dependency management could do the trick. It's working by mistake like that in one of my projects but can't figure out why, I suspect due to project dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so using `org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.2` solves my problem. It escapes properly javaDoc and generates classes with `javax.xml.bind...` imports.

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/gen/java</sourceRoot>
                            <xsdOptions>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xslt/MySchema.xsd</xsd>
                                    <packagename>some.package</packagename>
                                </xsdOption>
                            </xsdOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

After analysing dependencies it looks like the plugin uses `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3` which has `javax.xml.bind` as main package (which changes to `jakarta.xml.bind` starting with version `3.0.1`).

Comment: did you mange to also get jakarta validation or still javax.validation?